# Fetch all foreign key records from collection

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a table with *Users* and a table with *Cities* in my **MSSQL**.

In my *Users* table I have Id, Age, and City_Id with a foreign key to Id in *Cities*.

I am programming in **C#** and are using **Entity Framework** and want to get all cities with starting point in a collection of Users.

What I have is:

```
db.Users.Where(x => x.Age == 18)
```

How can I get all cities referenced in my collection of users above with **LINQ**, without the need for a foreach statement?

Something like?

```
db.Users.Where(x => x.Age == 18).Select(x => x.Cities)
```

This obviously don't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SelectMany:

```
db.Users.Where(x => x.Age == 18).SelectMany(x => x.Cities)
```

Also, as Andy points out, consider whether the potential for duplicates is valid. If not add Distinct:

```
db.Users.Where(x => x.Age == 18).SelectMany(x => x.Cities).Distinct()
```

Comment: You beat me, was just about to post this. I would add that he will probably also want `Distinct()` otherwise the result will possibly have duplicates.

Comment: Argh, I was actually close. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're close.

Try:

```
var results = db.Users.Where(u => u.Age == 18).SelectMany(c => c.City)
```

If you want a strongly-typed, enumerated list of cities then:

```
List<City> results = db.Users.Where(u => u.Age == 18)
                          .SelectMany(c => c.City).ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks alot, exactly what I wanted.